# Who releases the `DataBuffer`s passed to `ReactiveHttpOutputMessage#writeWith`?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I'm trying to write a custom `ReactiveHttpOutputMessage` implementation.  Should I release the `DataBuffer`s I receive in `writeWith`?  The default `ReactiveHttpOutputMessage` implementation `ReactorClientHttpRequest` doesn't but I'm not sure if it's intended or if it's a bug.